# How to get the radio button value from php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

i want to get the radio button value in php.The thing is i am having the drop down in one page, when i select some value from dropdown, it sends the value to ajax and php and from php page it is generating the radio button.

Now i want to get the radio button value. How can i get it?

code

index.php

```
   <script>
                    function showUser(str) {
                        if(str=="") {
                            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
                            return;
                        }

                        if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                        } else {
                            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                        }

                        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                            if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                            }
                        }
                        xmlhttp.open("GET","gettheater.php?q="+str,true);
                        xmlhttp.send();
                    }
    </script>


<div id="txtHint">


</div>
```

Code:
gettheater.php

```
<?php
$q = strtolower(trim($_GET["q"]));

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=theaterdb;host=localhost','tiger','tiger');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$sql = 'SELECT address FROM theater WHERE LOWER(theater_name) = :q';

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindValue(':q', $q);
$sth->execute();

echo "<form name='theater' method='POST'>";
echo "<table border='0' class='tabs'><tr><th>Theater Address</th><th>Select</th></tr>";

while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td class='ad'>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>"; 
  echo '<input type="radio" name="address" value="43"  />';
  echo "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";
echo "</form>";
$dbh = null;

?>
```

Comment: you want to access a radiobutton's value where? In your JavaScript or in your PHP code?

Comment: $addressRadio = $_POST['address']; print $addressRadio;

Comment: @Ygg I want to get the radio button's value in index.php

Comment: how do u want to get it? onclick or when checked? please specify the event

Comment: @Akam the index.php has one submit button. when i click submit button it has to get the selected radio button value...

Comment: ok, why the value is `43` is that just an example or real code?

Comment: the radio button's value will be sent with the form's POST request; if it is sent to index.php you can read it there from the global $_POST variable

Comment: @Akam the value 43 is example

Comment: ok if your form not uses any ajax, then, the one that checked will be available via $_POST['address'] and that's all.

Answer (score 0):

from a pure javascript point you can grab all the radio boxes with the name `address` and find the one that is selected.

```
function getSelectedValue() {
var addresses = document.getElementsByName('address');
for (var i=0; i < addresses.length; i++) {
   if (addresses[i].checked) return addresses[i].value;
}
}
```